# Change the "major dimension" that Orthographic Scale affects?

Tags: camera, dimensions, orthographic

I have an orthographic camera to capture a plane of width 1. When I set Orthographic Scale to 1,  the camera captures 1 unit of the space in the height dimension.

Can I change the "major dimension" that Orthographic Scale affects?

Comment: I think that the orthographic scale is referred to the widest between resolution height and width

Answer (score 0):

A bit confusingly worded question, but what I'm gathering is you want to know how to exclusively scale along the X, Y, and Z axes? (X and Y are horizontal, Z is vertical). All you have to do is after pressing <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, simply press <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd>. This will restrict your scale to whatever dimension you chose. Also, if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd> after pressing <kbd>S</kbd>, this will restrict scaling to every axis *except* the axis you selected. For example, <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will make your scaling *only* scale along the X and Y axes.

Comment: the op is not asking about how to scale along one particular axis...